# Unix command for find updated and newly added files/folder

Tags: unix, filesystems, find, command

I need to find out the listed for files or folders that has been added/updated in the file system path (`/home/user01/myapps/`) between two different time (scripts starting and ending time).

I am running a Shell scripts to do the updating/adding new files to the resource path `/home/user01/myapps/` from different source. So, at the end of scripts I want to know the list of files or folders that has been added or updated.

I have the below command

> find /opt/app/tds/tdsbatch -mtime -1

But, I am not sure about the script running time.

Any help indeed!

Comment: what do you mean 'not sure about the script running time'. Please update your question to include sample output you need. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To record times at whatever desired moment:

```
# record the current time in seconds on script startup
start_time=$(date +%s)
...
# do whatever you like
...
# to get the runtime in secods - if you like:
runtime=$(($(date +%s) - start_time))
# to get the runtime in minutes (minutes are useful for -mmin find param)
runtime=$((($(date +%s) - start_time) / 60))
...
# to record the finish time in seconds:
end_time=$(date +%s)
```

and now `find` according to your needs. something like

```
find /path \( -mmin $((-($(date +%s) - start_time) / 60)) \
  -a $((($(date +%s) - end_time) / 60)) \)
```

- the first `-mmin` argument specifies *modifed after (current time - script start time) minutes back from now*
- the second `-mmin` argument specifies *modified before (current time - script end time) minutes back from now*
- both of them are in conjunction with `-a` parameter and enclosed in prefixed brackets

You could probably do with these. Otherwise I would need more clarification about your needs.

Answer (score 0):

At the start of script you can use touch command for any existing file or create a dummy file.

e.g.

script start

touch filename1  - It will change the time stamp of filename1 to current time

Then at the end of script you can use following command:

find directory name -newer filename1

It will give all the files modified or created  after timestamp of filename1 in that directory